# How to update database colume where date is equals to current date of within 5days ago

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update my database in Laravel. I only need to update only where `created_at` is equal to current date or 5 days before.

I have tried the below code, but only updates the `created_at` field if it's equals to todays date. I want it to be also for 5 days back.

The below code works for only if `created_at` is equal to today:

```
$date = Carbon::today();

DB::table('product_stocks')->whereDate('created_at', '=', $date)
->update([
  'status' => 1
]);
```

Comment: Well of course this code only updates today... You're using `=`. If you want to check a date range (between now and 5 days ago), you need to use the proper code. I'll give you a hint; `whereBetween()` is a function that exists.

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try and let me know -

```
$from = Carbon::now()->subDays(5)->toDateTimeString(); 
$today = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

DB::table('product_stocks')->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $today])
    ->update([
       'status' => 1
    ]);
```

Comment: This code works bro...sorry for last response...the code works except that it didnt update todays field..it updated all except today

Comment: Use Carbon::now() instead of Carbon::today(). I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Carbon to have the date of 5 days ago

```
DB::table('product_stocks')->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(5))
->update([
  'status' => 1
]);
```

Comment: this looks like it..Thanks my friend...let me try and get back to you

Comment: Note sure why i got this .    -----> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> ?' at line 1 (SQL: update `product_stocks` set `status` = 1 where date(`created_at`) => 2019-09-29 18:02:35)

Comment: Finally worked man...Thank u bro...u saved my time...i love u..kisses